# Making input easy to read (Macaulay2)

Tags: indentation, osx

I am using Emacs to run Macaulay2 (I'm a newbie at both). I have a long input written in an `m2` file, which I then press `f11` to input to Macaulay2. I would like to make my input more aesthetically pleasing than one long line by, e.g. breaking it up into different lines. However, when I do this using `RET`, and then press `f11`, Macaulay2 only inputs whatever line my cursor is on (which is a fraction of my desired input).

So I'm looking for a way to create line breaks in the `m2` file without Macaulay2 interpreting them as different inputs.

**edit:** Here are some more details per Stefan's request: The mode is Macaulay2 and `f11` is running the command M2-send-to-program (found in M2-mode-map), which is an interactive lisp function in ‘M2.el’

[image]

Comment: `f11` is not bound by default in Emacs, so you must be using a particular mode, either builtin or installed from somewhere.  Please clarify what you've done in this respect.  Also you might like to indicate what command is run by `f11` which you can find with `C-h k f11`.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks for the comment. The mode is Macaulay2 and f11 is running the command M2-send-to-program (found in M2-mode-map), which is an interactive lisp function in ‘M2.el’

Comment: Please add that info to your question: comments are not always displayed and may get deleted.